# split tori over local fields

Tags: group-schemes, local-fields

Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, and $\mathscr O$ its ring of integers. Suppose $T$ is an $F$-split torus, i.e., $T = (\mathbb G_m)^r$ where $\mathbb G_m$ denotes the multiplicative group. Can someone explain to me what is meant by the following (and why it is true): there is a unique $\mathscr O$-torus structure on the $F$-torus $T$?

Thanks in advance, 
AYK.

Comment: Is there a reference you are looking at?  If so, please give the reference.  Almost certainly this refers to flat group schemes over $\text{Spec}\mathcal{O}$ that are 'etale locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m^r$.

Comment: Yes there is actually, I was trying to understand certain statements in the notes below: 

http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/JLseminar/Notes/L4.pdf

(see beginning of p.3)

Comment: Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth group schemes over $\text{Spec}\mathcal{O}$ that are each 'etale locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{\mathcal{O},m}^r$.  Let $i_F:M_F\to N_F$ be a homomorphism of algebraic $F$-group schemes of the generic fibers.  Check, 'etale locally, that there is a unique homomorphism $i:M\to N$ of algebraic group schemes over $\text{Spec}\mathcal{O}$ whose generic fiber is $i_F$.  Now apply this to prove that every isomorphism of $M_F$ and $N_F$ extends uniquely to an isomorphism of $M$ and $N$.